# Use applymap on DataFrame but keep index/column info

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing an Event Study on some stocks, which results in a pandas DataFrame where the columns are the stock ticker symbol (SPY, GOOG, AAPL, etc)  and the indices are the timestamps.  The cells within the DataFrame have a value of NaN or 1.  I would like to generate an orders DataFrame based off of the events DataFrame.  Since I want to create an order for every time the cell == 1, I thought applymap would be appropriate.  However, it appears that using applymap strips the cell of it's index and column.  I tried the code below:

```
def appendOrder(orders, value):
    if value == 1:
        index = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Stock", "OrderType", "Amount"]
        s = pd.Series(index=index)
        s["Stock"] = value.index

def createOrders(events):
    columns = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Stock", "OrderType", "Amount"]

    orders = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    events.applymap(lambda x: appendOrder(orders,x))
```

The code above breaks in the appendOrder method since value has no index.

**Is there anyway to retain the index and column information when applymap is used on a DataFrame?**

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet of the events DataFrame:

```
                     SPY    GOOG    AAPL    XOM
2013-10-1-16:00:00   NaN     1      NaN      1
2013-10-2-16:00:00   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-10-3-16:00:00   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-10-4-16:00:00   1      NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-10-5-16:00:00   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-10-6-16:00:00   1      NaN     1       NaN
2013-10-7-16:00:00   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-10-8-16:00:00   NaN    1       NaN     NaN
```

I would like turn the above events DataFrame into the orders DataFrame below:

```
     Year     Month    Day   Stock    OrderType    Amount
0    2013      10       1    GOOG       Buy         100
1    2013      10       1    XOM        Buy         100
2    2013      10       4    SPY        Buy         100
3    2013      10       6    SPY        Buy         100
4    2013      10       6    AAPL       Buy         100
5    2013      10       8    GOOG       Buy         100
```

I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and what you'd like the output to look like? I'm not sure applymap is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis for that pandas operation is called [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.stack()
Out[25]: 
2013-10-1-16:00:00  GOOG    1
                    XOM     1
2013-10-4-16:00:00  SPY     1
2013-10-6-16:00:00  SPY     1
                    AAPL    1
2013-10-8-16:00:00  GOOG    1
```

Working and tuning your data from the stacked dataframe above is straightforward. You can follow by resetting the index, split it into year month day columns, and apply the math on the non NaN data that are in a single column now.